# LevelDB: Implementing an iterator to enumerate by key prefix

Tags: iterator, c++-cli, leveldb

I am looking for an efficient way to implement a key enumerator using leveldb to iterate by a key-prefix.  The key is byte array (and the db uses default byte array comparer, so all keys with specific prefix stored/retrieved sequentially), and I would like my iterator to be able to take a key prefix and return only the data with keys having that prefix.

Do I have to use or inherit the default db iterator, seek to the first key in the range (ofcourse I need to know what it is), and then verify and return every slice that starts with the prefix (by overriding the movenext or something)? or is there a more efficient way of implementing this?

Let me know if anybody has solved this already and can share the code or the general idea.  I am trying this from C++/CLI, but implementation in any language would help.

Thanks.
-raj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparator is used to determine if the keys are different, so overloading it wouldn't help because as you're scanning the database- you have to be able to compare the full keys (not just the prefixes). Overloading the iterator is not necessary: the keys are ordered in leveldb, you would know that if you encounter a key with a different prefix, it will already be out of the range. You can just use the iterator as you normally would and as long as your keys are evaluated properly, you should get the right results:

```
void ScanRecordRange(const leveldb::Slice& startSlice, const leveldb::Slice& endSlice)
{
    // Get a database iterator
    shared_ptr<leveldb::Iterator> dbIter(_database->NewIterator(leveldb::ReadOptions()));

    // Possible optimization suggested by Google engineers 
    // for critical loops. Reduces memory thrash.
    for(dbIter->Seek(startSlice); dbIter->Valid() && _options.comparator->Compare(dbIter->key(), endSlice)<=0 ;dbIter->Next())
    {                
        // Read the record
        if( !dbIter->value().empty() )
        {
            leveldb::Slice keySlice(dbIter->key());
            leveldb::Slice dataSlice(dbIter->data());
            // TODO: process the key/data

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Lirik.  Yes, I had seen similar example in leveldb documentation.  This does retrieve the range [startSlice, endSlice].  However, my 'prefix' problem was that I wouldn't know the endSlice, and also my keys are not all the same size/length.  But as you said, I guess I could use the default iterator, and instead of comparing the full key for <=, I will have to take the part that's as long as the input prefix and compare for equality with the input. I just wish leveldb provided this function with optimal implementation. :)

Comment: You can construct an `endKey` with the desired prefix that would allow you to iterate until you read all the keys. Here is an example of an end key: 0xC7D8FFFF, your prefix is C7D8 and FFFF would be the rest of the key; and your start key would be 0xC7D80000. However, I don't understand why your keys are of different length, are you using strings? If so, you should hash the strings using CityHash and use fixed length 64-bit or 128-bit keys. Hashing the keys would make this **a lot** easier!

Comment: Well, my keys are byte arrays; but it's of different length as I am using leveldb as patricia trie to store/retrieve a tree of nodes with certain criteria to ensure direct children are stored/retrieved sequentially to/from disk before their grand children, etc. -- so deeper the node is, longer the key gets as it would contain the parent key info as prefix etc.!

Comment: CityHash uses byte arrays too, it just outputs a fixed length hash, which would definitely help you search for key ranges. However, you have to ensure that consecutive byte arrays you use for keys result in consecutive keys when hashed as well. Otherwise, you can do another trick and assume fixed length keys for your trees as long as you know what would be the maximum depth (if you have one).

Answer (score 0):

I have a prefix iterator in [my LevelDB wrapper](https://github.com/ArtemGr/libglim/blob/master/ldb.hpp).
It is used in the range returned by `startsWith` method:

```
int count = 0;
for (auto& en: ldb.startsWith (std::string ("prefix"))) {++count;}
```

Comment: This has the same weakness as the official sample code - if there is a custom comparator in the database then you are comparing your end keys here differently from how that custom comparator works.

Comment: @AndyDent, Thanks for noticing. If you need this functionality please submit a feature request.

Comment: I "noticed" the hard way - made exactly the same mistake in my code for the book and propagated through about three examples before I got to writing a custom comparator and my iteratorRange failed ;-)

Comment: Well I'm using a custom comparator with BDB-JE and it increased the maintance costs, e.g. using view/backup/repair tools is more complicated, so with LevelDB I stayed away from custom comparators so far.